# Laravel 4 Build Query where clause on the fly

Tags: php, laravel

I am porting my code from CodeIgniter to Laravel. and have some question regarding the query builder.

In codeigniter, I can just add where clause to the active record object, as I initialize each property in a class like

```
$this->db->where('xxxx','bbbb');
```

in one property initialize function, and

```
$this->db->where('yyyy','aaaa');
```

in another property function, and it will all chain up until i fire off the query. But this doesn't seem to be the case of Laravel.

Here is what I do in laravel in each property initialize function

```
DB::table($this->table)->where('xxxx','bbbb');
DB::table($this->table)->where('yyyy','aaa');
```

and when a actual method is call from outside, it runs

```
DB:table($this->table)->get();
```

but this gives me a `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME` without anywhere clause. So what am I doing wrong here :x or I just shouldn't treat laravel same as codeigniter and think of something totally different to handle this kind of dynamic where clause?

Also in codeigniter, you can set a section of the query to cache, so even after you fire off the query , those section retains for next query, usually the where clause. Is there a similar function in Laravel? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign your current workings to a variable, and build upon that, let me show you an example based on your example:

Instead of this

```
DB::table($this->table)->where('xxxx','bbbb');
DB::table($this->table)->where('yyyy','aaa');
```

Try this...

```
$query = DB::table($this->table)->where('xxxx','bbbb');
$query->where('yyyy','aaa');

$results = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. exactly what I need to get the query rolling :)

Answer (score 0):

> I just shouldn't treat laravel same as codeigniter and think of something totally different to handle this kind of dynamic where clause?

This is not dynamic where clause.

and please, make a habit of reading the documentation.

From the docs of **[Fluent query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)**

`$users = DB::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();`

*you can set a section of the query to cache, so even after you fire off the query , those section retains for next query, usually the where clause. Is there a similar function in Laravel?*

`$users = DB::table('users')->remember(10)->get();`

Next time, just open up the docs. they contain all this.

Comment: I did came across that part. But to my understanding, it's for caching the query result rather than the where clause. I need the cache to on where clause only, so when I initiate a class, it's all prepared for further operation on different data columns. Maybe it's different from CI that I expect something that I have to initiate a cache start and cache end session in order to archive what I need. I will sure dig down deeper to the documentation when I got more time, Thanks.

Comment: Just a misunderstanding here. When talking about retaining for next query, OP was referring to being able to build up the query over multiple statements, as opposed to in a single chained statement.

Comment: @duellsy lol yeah. you got it right. he said **cache** so i thought it was about _caching_.